# Unable to unbind the ldap connection when there is an active query

Tags: openldap

ldap_unbind_ext is blocked until the previously initaited ldap search is completed.

I initiate search and unfortunately server takes 3+ minutes to respond.Meanwhile if I attempt to register to another server, the old connection should be tore down and a new connection should be established by my application.
But,as there is an active query on the old connection,ldap_unbind_ext gets blocked until search is completed.

I tried using ldap_abandon_ext before we call ldap_unbind_ext ,but now it blocks in ldap_abandon_ext .

Could someone help me on this.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using ldap_pvt_tls_destroy shall destroy the connection though there is an active query on the connection.

We need this when we tear down a connection, to allow the global TLS settings to change.
This function is called in ldapsearch, in its tool_destroy() routine, and also in slapd.